# How to stop a "watch" process

Tags: process, watch

I use "[Pleeease"](http://pleeease.io) to watch CSS files and automatically compile them when any change happens. I did

```
pleeease watch
```

and then just close the terminal, the wathcing process keeps running. Now I want to restart the watch process because I have editted the watch options, but I don't know how to find the process and kill it. I am very new to linux, did a little goolgling and "ps -A" is as far as I can get, but I don't see anything similar to "pleeease watch" in the list. Do I have to reboot?

Answer (score 1):

You could try

1. `killall pleeease` to kill **all** instances of `pleeease`; it will tell you when it couldn't find any.
2. `ps -A | grep pleeease` to filter the output of `ps` for the process you're looking for, then use `kill` with the process ID.
3. `pgrep pleeease` as a variation of 2. to just get the PID(s) instead of the complete `ps` line (which may make it hard to distinguish them if there are more of them).